# Missing modules with cx_freeze

Tags: python, numpy, import, cx-freeze

I'm trying to compile a python projet to an executable file cx_freeze. The `python setup.py build` command works, I have my .exe file created but when I want to execute it I have an Original exception error message:

```
Exception raised when calling format_exception
Exception: 'str' object has no attribute '__cause__'
Original exception: cannot import name _methods
```

In the compilation log file I found many imports errors:

```
Missing modules:
? IPython.utils.generics imported from pandas.core.panel
? PIL imported from matplotlib.image
? PyQt4.QtCore imported from matplotlib.backends.qt4_compat
? Pyrex.Compiler.Main imported from numpy.distutils.command.build_src
? StringIO imported from six
? UserDict imported from pytz
? __config__ imported from numpy.distutils
? _curses imported from curses
? _frozen_importlib imported from pkg_resources
? _gestalt imported from platform
? _transforms imported from matplotlib.dates
? bottleneck imported from pandas.core.nanops
? cPickle imported from xlsxwriter.compat_collections
? cStringIO imported from pkg_resources
? compiler imported from numpy.lib.utils
? gobject imported from matplotlib.pyplot
? has_key imported from curses
? md5 imported from matplotlib.texmanager
? mpl_toolkits.natgrid imported from matplotlib.mlab
? multiprocessing._multiprocessing imported from multiprocessing.forking
? nose imported from numpy.testing.nosetester
? numarray imported from numpy.distutils.system_info
? numexpr imported from pandas.core.expressions
? numpy.core._dotblas imported from numpy.core.numeric
? numpy.core.exp imported from numpy.linalg.linalg
? numpy.core.integer imported from numpy.fft.helper
? numpy.core.signbit imported from numpy.testing.utils
? numpy.e imported from numpy.numarray.functions
? numpy_distutils imported from numpy.f2py.diagnose
? openpyxl.reader.excel imported from pandas.io.parsers
? pudb imported from pandas.util.testing
? pyemf imported from matplotlib.backends.backend_emf
? qt imported from matplotlib.pyplot
? scikits.statsmodels.api imported from pandas.stats.ols
? scipy imported from numpy.testing.nosetester
? sets imported from numpy.lib.function_base
? setuptools imported from numpy.distutils.core
? sip imported from matplotlib.backends.qt4_compat
? statsmodels.api imported from pandas.stats.ols
? sysconfig imported from pkg_resources
? tables imported from pandas.io.pytables
? thread imported from dateutil.rrule
? urlparse imported from pkg_resources
? wx imported from matplotlib.pyplot
? xlrd imported from pandas.io.parsers
? xlwt imported from pandas.io.parsers
```

I've searched for some of those not imported files but they are not on my computer obviously. So I suspected errors of librairies installations but it doesn't seem to be that. I installed all twice. What else could it be ?

I'm using Python 3.1, cx_freeze 4.2.3, matplotlib 1.2.0, pandas 0.11.0, and numpy 1.7.1.

Here's my setup.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
#############################################################################
path = sys.path + ["."]

includes = ['json', 'xml', 'PySide', 'xml.sax', 'xml.etree', 'xml.etree.ElementTree','xml.etree.cElementTree','xml.etree.ElementInclude','test',
            'test.support','runpy','ctypes.util','logging.config','configparser','ctypes.wintypes','zipfile','sqlite3', 'io', 'subprocess', 
            'zlib','atexit','csv','pandas','matplotlib','numpy','xlsxwriter','re','itertools','os','sys']

include_files = []
excludes = []
packages = ['numpy.lib.format']
options = {"path": path,
           "includes": includes,
           "excludes": excludes,
           "packages": packages,
           "include_files": include_files,
           "build_exe": "C:/temp/Test/",
           "create_shared_zip" :False}
#############################################################################

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
cible_1 = Executable(
    script = "D:/eDoc/src/Tool/main.py",
    base = base,
    compress = True,
    appendScriptToExe = True,
    appendScriptToLibrary = False,
    copyDependentFiles = True,
    targetName = 'Tool.exe',
    targetDir = "C:/temp/Test/")

buildOptions = dict(create_shared_zip = False)
    #############################################################################
setup(
    name = 'Tool',
    version = '1',
    description = '' ,
    author = '',
    options = {'build_exe': options},
    executables = [cible_1])
```

And here my imports in main.py

```
import sys
import os
import functools
import configparser
import time
import subprocess
import itertools
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

#import matplotlib dependencies to merge Pyside and matplotlib plot
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('wxAgg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend']='qt4agg'
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import PySide
from PySide import QtCore,QtGui,QtUiTools
from PySide.QtUiTools import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
```

Anyone has an idea of what could be the cause of that issue ?